# Copying many files without extension into one main folder via batch

Tags: file, batch-file, copy, paste

Right now I have this:

```
@echo off 
xcopy C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\assets\objects\**\* C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\assets\objects\extracted 
pause
```

Basicly what this is supposed to do it copy all the files from the subfolders of objects into a folder called extracted, but it says "File not found - * ; 0 Files Copied ; Press any key to continue"

There are 528 files that need to be all dumped into one folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
cd C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\assets\objects
for /D %%a in (*) do (
   if "%%a" neq "extracted" xcopy "%%a\*" extracted /I
)
pause
```